# Delphi JSON ObjectToJsonString with class/records

Tags: json, delphi

I am trying to encode some sample data into JSON format.

The code below works...

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, REST.Json.Types, REST.Json;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TSub = record
    yone: string;
    ytwo: string;
    ythree: string
  end;

  TJTest = class
    Xone: string;
    Xtwo: string;
    Xthree: string;
    Xarray: Array of TSub;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JT: TJTest;
begin
  JT := TJTest.Create;
  JT.XOne := 'X1';
  JT.Xtwo := 'X2';
  JT.Xthree := 'X3';
  SetLength(JT.Xarray, 2);
  JT.Xarray[0].yone := 'England';
  JT.Xarray[0].ytwo := 'Scotland';
  JT.Xarray[0].ythree := 'Wales';
  JT.Xarray[1].yone := 'New Zealand';
  JT.Xarray[1].ytwo := 'Australia';
  JT.Xarray[1].ythree := 'Fiji';
  Memo2.Lines.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(JT);
end;

end.
```

however it does not output the pair names for Xarray.

I tried changing TSub to a class but then I get an exception.

What can I change to get pair names to be included?

Comment: The default Delphi serializer serializes records as an array of its field values. When you change `TSub` to a class type, then you need to instantiate it by calling constructor before accessing its members (fields), otherwise you might get an access violation exception: `JT.Xarray[0] := TSub.Create;`, `JT.Xarray[1] := TSub.Create;` and so on ...